# EROR when try to reach twilio API from China environment (Remote host closed connection during handshake)

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, twilio

When I try to send SMS in the China AWS environment in logs I got an exception. What can cause this issue? Is Twilio API is nor reachable from the China region? When we run this in not China environments sending SMS process works correctly.
I try to send SMS to not Chinese user.(Ukraine for example)

```
020-11-20 13:06:36,597 ERROR (ID 9f95d1c6-f082-4729-8dc2-22f4f71860c0) (USER ) (SRC c.m.d.c.c.ejb) (REQ POST /carePartners/changeStatus) ConnectEJB.sms 'dihik' [server name: null, max mem (mb): 5813, total mem (mb): 5813, free mem (mb): 4781, used mem (mb): 1032, dihik, loaded account in 5, [ConnectEJB.sms], alarm UUID: null, +38093 118 6575, smsVendor=TwilioSMS, toPhoneNum=+38093 118 6575, submitted in 735, ERROR]: java.lang.RuntimeException: 'dihik' sending SMS: com.medtronic.diabetes.carelink.connect.sms.SMSException: Remote host closed connection during handshake; com.twilio.exception.ApiException Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at com.medtronic.diabetes.carelink.connect.ejb.ConnectSMSBean.onMessageWorker(ConnectSMSBean.java:165)
    at com.medtronic.diabetes.carelink.connect.ejb.AbstractConnectBean.executeWorkerContext(AbstractConnectBean.java:336)
```

Comment: This is usually caused by GFW interfering the TCP handshake.

Comment: How we can fix that?

Comment: It's a known problem if the traffic go through the internet crossing the Chinese border. The only real solution is to get a leased line.